# Why are they called delayed integrators

Tags: control, control-system, laplace-transform

I'm quite confused as to why we call a system with transfer function $$\frac{1}{s+\alpha}$$
a delayed integrator.

It does not seem to be an integrator in the first place since it convolves with an exponential unless alpha is 0.

Comment: Probably because of the pole introduced by \$\alpha\$, which causes the slope to come later, than starting with DC. Personally, I haven't heard this term, but don't count on my technical English.

Comment: [This table of Laplace transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Laplace_transforms) classifies it as an exponential decay (assuming \$a > 0\$), though I suppose it could become exponential growth if \$a < 0\$. Other tables I referenced list something similar, sometimes tabulating for \$e^{a t}\$ instead of \$e^{-a t}\$